# extract string from another using awk

Tags: shell, ash

I have this variable which contain a list of string separted by space

```
val=00:21:5D:16:F3 00:21:5D:16:F4 00:21:5D:16:F5
```

I want to extract each string separated bu space " " and then assign it to `val`
I use this shell code  but it doesn't work

```
while [ "$((i++))" != "10" ]; do
   val$i=`echo $val | awk '{print $i}'`
   echo "val$i=$val$i"
done
```

the desired result is :

```
val1="00:21:5D:16:F3"
val2="00:21:5D:16:F4"
val3="00:21:5D:16:F5"
val4=""
val5=""
val6=""
val7=""
val8=""
val9=""
val10=""
```

any help is appreciated even if the  treatment is done with another linux utility like cut , sed , grep.

Comment: Do oyu necessarily want to do it with awk or other solutions are considered too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help  and I want to share with you the best solution that I found

```
while [ "$((i++))" != "10" ]; do
   val$i=`echo $val | awk -F' ' '{print $'"$i"'}'`
   echo "val$i=$val$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

this awk script should be what are you looking for

```
awk -F[' '=] 'BEGIN{t=1} { for (i=2;i<=11;i++) {print "val" t "=\"" $i "\""; t+=1}}' test
```

there is output

```
system1:/depot/scripts/sh # awk -F[' '=] 'BEGIN{t=1} { for (i=2;i<=11;i++) {print "val" t "=\"" $i "\""; t+=1}}' test
val1="00:21:5D:16:F3"
val2="00:21:5D:16:F4"
val3="00:21:5D:16:F5"
val4=""
val5=""
val6=""
val7=""
val8=""
val9=""
val10=""
system:/depot/scripts/sh #
```

test file contains:

```
system:/depot/scripts/sh # cat test
val=00:21:5D:16:F3 00:21:5D:16:F4 00:21:5D:16:F5
system:/depot/scripts/sh #
```

Comment: we can do that with another linux utility like cut , sed , grep, to avoid this long treatment

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Why do you want to use another 3 commands when it is possible to do it by one on one line?

Answer (score 0):

I Know is not what you really asked, but what about using array to solve this?

like:

val=(00:21:5D:16:F3 00:21:5D:16:F4 00:21:5D:16:F5)

$ echo ${val[0]}

```
00:21:5D:16:F3
```

$ echo ${val[1]}

```
00:21:5D:16:F4
```

$ echo ${val[2]}

```
00:21:5D:16:F5
```

$ echo ${val[3]}